# Keto diet or protein diet for building muscle?

Tags: muscle-gain, ketogenic-diet, high-protein

I have researched about keto diets and protein diets and I was wondering which would be better to do when trying to build muscle. Keto diets allow your body to produce energy much more efficiently, but you can get worn out quickly when doing intense exercise. Protein diets provide you with constant energy, but your body isn't as efficient and some of the protein gets converted to fat.

Is it better to follow a keto diet or a protein diet when trying to build muscle?

Comment: How about a balanced human diet with some extra protein without any stupidity? Making artificial constraints to earn some people money (that's the motivation behind all diets you hear about) will never be as good as eating like humans are supposed to eat. High protein is the #1 food trend right now, the best seller. Don't be fooled. A bit extra is plenty. Carbs are not the devil. Don't waste time and money on by definition suboptimal approaches, even if it makes barely a difference. There is no rational reason, just some pseudo science and marketing

Comment: What is a protein diet?

Comment: @Dark Hippo A diet that includes consuming large amounts of protein *and possibly carbohydrates* in order to provide your body with the energy and resources required to build muscle efficiently.

Comment: Keto will actually cause muscle loss. Some people use it for fat loss but only see results after a month losing mostly water weight, or around 30 lbs total..then the moment they stop the diet, all the weight is gained back so they are on keto forever to basically keep 30 lbs off. Keto puts your body in starving "survival" mode, slowing down your metabolism,creating ketones which can have an effect on brain health. It hurts your organs having a diet only consisting of fat and protein, and can cause heart problems. Even Schwarzenegger mentions keto being bad. Just eat clean and count calories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure where you got the idea that a keto diet "produces energy more efficiently" but thats not really true. in fact, I would argue that doing a keto diet would negatively impact your energy because the primary fuel source for muscle is glycogen. glycogen is stored within the muscle and its mobilised for ATP production during periods of energy demand. In my experience a nice balanced diet is all you need, provided you are eating sufficient calories during the day. in terms of protein, you should aim for about 1.2 grams of protein per lb of body weight. you could consume more than that but there have been studies that show that any extra protein is expelled from your body.